# Is a Base64 encoded string completely alphanumeric?

Tags: encoding, base64

Is a Base64 encoded string completely alphanumeric except for the "=" at the end?

Answer (score 8):

As there are only 26 letters in the alphabet, and ten digits, you only have 26+26+10=62 distinct alpanumeric characters. As base64 obviously needs 64, two additional characters are needed. These two are `+` and slash `/`. Additionally, as you said, `=` is used as padding at the end of message, if necessary.